# Magento2 Add Quote ID in Sales Order Grid

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-grid

I am trying to display quote id of an order in the sales order grid. New field is getting displayed in the grid. However the value of the quote id is not getting populated in the grid against each order.

How to show the `quote id` from the sales. I believe `di.xml` needs to be added for it work. I am not sure how the `di.xml` needs to be.

Here is the code **view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_grid.xml**

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<columns name="sales_order_columns">
    <column name="quote_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Quote Id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: Which version you have tried?

Comment: Magento version 2.0.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add sequence tag inside module.xml

```
<sequence>
    <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
</sequence>
```

Create Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sales_order_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">sales_order_grid</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Create Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult;

class Collection extends SearchResult
{
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->join(
            [$this->getTable('sales_order')],
            'main_table.entity_id = '.$this->getTable('sales_order').'.entity_id',
            array('quote_id')
        );

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Run following command and clear cache

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Does it differ for Magento 2.1.x?

Comment: For M2.1 grid collection class already exist. So in that case you can do it using overwrite.

Comment: if you can provide information on how to add for 2.1 that would be helpful because I need it for both versions

Comment: good news is, it's also works with M2.1

Comment: this answer is good, but without ui component config, for it check here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/134890/23344

Comment: If we use this steps for showing quote_id,Quote_id is showing in order_grid in Sales/Orders.But Customer/Customer Information->Order Tab is not showing.Please guide me.@SohelRana

Comment: This is screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0kJq.png .

Comment: Please help me @SohelRana

Comment: Hey @LovelySetia can you post your problem and tag to me. I will help you tonight.

Comment: ok, i will tag you in my  post. @SohelRana