# Order Grid is not showing in Customer->Customer Information(Orders) Admin Panel in Magento-2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, admin-panel, order-grid

Order Grid is not showing in Customer->Customer Information(Orders Tab) on admin Panel in Magento-2.1?Please check screenshot  https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0kJq.png
What is issue in this? Please guide me.

Comment: can you enable error app/bootstrap.php uncomment ini_set('display_errors', 1) ?

Then check if here is any error

Comment: where error is show? @AnsarHusain

Comment: first check error log/access log

Comment: I will use this this module https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132980/magento2-add-quote-id-in-sales-order-grid  ,If we delete this module,then customer_order_grid is showing.Please guide me.

Comment: Hi, @SohelRana I will use your module https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132980/magento2-add-quote-id-in-sales-order-grid .After that install,order_grid is not showing in Magento->Customer->Customer Information(Order Tab).If i delete this module,it works fine.

Comment: have you check that @SohelRana ?

Comment: please guide me @SohelRana