# Why Order tab of Customer Information Section is not showing in Magento-2.2.7?

Tags: customer-account, admin-panel, order-grid, magento2.2.7

Order Tab is showing Blank when i click on the following path in admin panel:

`Customers->Edit(Particular Customer)->Click on Order Tab of Customer`

Information Section. This is the  screenshot  [Blank Order Tab](https://paste.pics/4R5NA)

Please help me for solve this issue in `Magento-2.2.7`

Comment: do you have custom module that overrides core order module?

Comment: yes, I will use this module https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132980/magento2-add-quote-id-in-sales-order-grid .

Comment: try to disable that one and check if order tab is blank or not

Comment: after disable,it is working but how to show quote_id in order_grid.Please guide me @magefms

Comment: try this solution with your own requirement, this should help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134754/magento-2-how-to-add-a-new-column-to-orders-grid/134890#134890

Comment: this solution is for creating new column in sales_order table,but in my requirements quote_id is already in sales_order table. @magefms

Comment: what do you want? add the quote id in sales order grid?

Comment: yes @magefms ..

Comment: I have added answer please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

EDIT:

Add in or add an **`InstallSchema.php`** from this path of your custom module:

> Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallSchema.php

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */
public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;

    $installer->startSetup();

    /* While module install, creates column in sales_order_grid table */

    $eavTable = $installer->getTable('sales_order_grid');

    $columns = [
        'quote_id' => [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment' => 'Quote Id',
        ],
    ];

    $connection = $installer->getConnection();
    foreach ($columns as $name => $definition) {
        $connection->addColumn($eavTable, $name, $definition);
       }

    $installer->endSetup();
}
}
```

Add this line in your **`di.xml`**

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="quote_id" xsi:type="string">sales_order.quote_id</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Then create a **`sales_order_grid.xml`** from this path of your custom_module:

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="quote_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
            </item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Quote Id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Note: Don't forget to run **`setup:upgrade`** then **`setup:static-content:deploy`** after.

Comment: it showing blank quote_id in order_grid. Please see this https://paste.pics/4SW6I @magefms

Comment: try to create a new order and check again , this does not apply to current orders during installation

Comment: **quote id** will only be generated once order is placed. check again with the new order

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check again.

Comment: I will run both commands,but this column is not created in sales_order_grid .And it show error when order is placed. @magefms

Comment: not in sales_order but sales_order_grid

Comment: also make sure to disable first your custom module

Comment: and re enable it again to apply the installSchema

Comment: It showing this error :  Order saving error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'quote_id' in 'field list', query was: INSERT INTO `sales_order_grid() . We disable this module first and after that re-enable it. @magefms

Comment: the custom module should be totally disabled (I mean it should be removed in the setup_module table in the schema

Comment: Yes,its working.Can i show old order quote id also?

Comment: cannot since that solution only works for the new order after installation. What it actually does it to pass quote_id to the grid after placing an order which means old quote_id is not included. :(

Comment: ok thanxxx alot!!!!!!!!